# Highcharts - Format X axis with 2 digit hours in 24 hour format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm looking to format the X-axis in a kind of bespoke way, see attached image. The format should be in time, in 24 hour but displayed as in the image - 9, 10, 11, 12, etc.

The Y Axis values are variable, which makes things tricky. For example, they could be alphabetical, numbers or other categories that don't have any relationship with time. Am I better off using the `datetime` or just using integers for this?

So far it looks like this but it's not working as expected:

```
const chartOptions = {
  title: {
    text: ""
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%H'
     }
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 10, 0, 5, 0), 1.09],
        [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 10, 0, 10, 0), 1.09]
      ],
      type: "line"
    }
  ]
};
```

What I want to achieve:

https://snipboard.io/RO4NLw.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `datetime` and `linear` type of xAxis. To have only hours in a `datetime` axis set:

```
xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        hour: '%k'
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/okeujzmh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats